# Spring converter to convert null to empty collection

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, typeconverter

I have a spring mvc 3.0 Web application.

I am using Spring Converters (no PropertyEditors) to convert id's (String) to Domain Entities. This even works for collections out of the box without any problems.
For example to populate a Set of Entities in a Form-Object from the user selection within an HTML multi select box.

Except in the case where the user selects nothing. Then the property (`Set<Entity> selection`) of Form-Object gets `null`. Even if I assign an empty collection to that property in the constructor of the Form-Object.
Every time the Form-Object gets populated with an http request that does not contain a user selection, the `selection` gets replaced by `null`. But I want it an empty collection!

So my question is: How to configure Spring Converters to populate an `Collection` field with empty collection instead of null, if the converter input is empty? -- Or even better to ignore the field at all if the input is empty.

Answer (score 0):

you could do a custom binder for Set, but may be it be easier to just put an if-else (check for null) inside the getter/ setter for `selection` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a setter on your object that is being called with null, just handle the null.  For example,

```
public void setBlammy(Set<String> newValue)
{
  if (newValue != null)
  {
    blammy = newValue;
  }
  else
  {
    blammy = new HashSet<String>();
  }
}
```